# Angular asynchronous Schematics stop working after migrating to Angular 9: A rule can't return a Tree or an Observable<Tree> anymore

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I have a function with the ability to call out to a service and use the resulting data object response from the service to be used to generate the CRUD code necessary to interact with that endpoint. So I created an asynchronous Schematic that would call to a service, wait for that service to respond, and then continue when we were ready.

My code is something like this:

```
function waitingRule(options: any): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree) => {
    return new Observable<Tree>((observer) => {
      fetch('someUrl.com/') // any async operation
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          observer.next(tree);
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(((err: any) => {
          observer.error(err);
        });
    });
  };
}
```

This worked well until I upgraded to Angular 9. Now I get the following error:

> Type '(tree: Tree) => Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Rule'. Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'void | Tree
> | Rule | Observable | Promise<void | Rule>'.

In previous versions a rule can return either a Tree or an Observable, but it seems this is not possible with the last versions. Any idea of how making this working again?

Comment: you can use "|" to indicate that a function (or a variable) can be type of one or another type: `waitingRule(options: any): Rule|Observable<Tree>{...}`. NOTE: In typescript you don't write "function" before a function

Comment: That doesn't work. I get the following error: "Type 'Rule | Observable<Tree>' is not assignable to type 'Rule'."